# How to Fix Puppeteer chromium-browserxdg-settings: not found Problem?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Recently we have updated our Ubuntu server hard Disk, after updating I am getting errors when I try to scrape data using puppeteer as mentioned below:

```
Could not create a browser instance => :  Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
1|app  | /usr/bin/chromium-browser: 12: xdg-settings: not found
1|app  | cannot perform operation: umount --no-follow /var/lib/snapd/hostfs//tmp/snap.rootfs_grFzK6: Invalid argument
1|app  | TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
1|app  |     at onClose (/home/secfusionread/scrape/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:193:20)
1|app  |     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/secfusionread/scrape/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:184:79)
```

My Puppeteer connection code below, I was able to scrape data before the updating.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function startBrowser() {
  let browser;
  //console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
  try {
    console.log("----------- Open the browser ------------");
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      // userDataDir: "../cache",
      executablePath:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
          : "",
      args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas",
        "--no-first-run",
        "--no-zygote",
        "--single-process",
        "--disable-gpu",
      ],
      headless: true,
      timeout: 6000,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Could not create a browser instance => : ", err);
  }
  return browser;
}

async function startPage(browser) {
  let page;
  try {
    console.log("----------- Open a new page ------------");
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 800 });
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    });
    await page.setUserAgent(
      "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
      // "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
    );
    // await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    // page.on("request", (req) => {
    //   if (req.resourceType() === "font" || req.resourceType() === "image") {
    //     req.abort();
    //   } else {
    //     req.continue();
    //   }
    // });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Could not create a new page => : ", err);
  }
  return page;
}

module.exports = {
  startBrowser,
  startPage,
};
```

chromium-browser exists in `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`, I tried a lot of code from google but nothing works.

Comment: have you run `ldd chrome | grep not` command on the server since the update? as mentioned in: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix

Comment: ldd: ./chrome found.

Comment: do you mean that has been the output of `ldd`? I'd assume it said `not found` or similar. you need to navigate to your chrome's folder, e.g.: `ldd /usr/bin/chromium-browser | grep not` (or `grep NEEDED`) if everything is good it will not list dependencies, but if it list some: you need to install them (they may lost with the Ubuntu upgrade)

Comment: `xdg-settings` (from your error msg) for example is included in [`xdg-utils`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xdg-utils) which is a direct dependency to puppeteer over Debian.

Comment: First I have executed ldd chrome | grep not, and it returns ldd: ./chrome found, next I have executed ldd /usr/bin/chromium-browser and it returns "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: I see, it seems the executable is within the `chromium-browser` folder (not itself the executable. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3138. sometimes `whereis chrome` (google-chrome etc.) helps. anyway I post a generic answer that may helps, as I am convinced it is a dependency-related issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is a missing dependency-related issue, which needs to be re-installed after Ubuntu was changed (hardware update under the server).

Even the error msg states this: `xdg-settings` for example is included in [`xdg-utils`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xdg-utils) which is a direct dependency to puppeteer over Debian.

The exact missing libraries can be retrieved with: `ldd /usr/bin/chromium-browser/<EXECUTABLE> | grep not`. (you need to retrieve the `<EXECUTABLE>`'s value for yourself, you can use the command [`whereis`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-whereis-command-examples-to-locate-binary/))

The usual Debian (Ubuntu) dependencies are the following that need to be installed:

```sh
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 lsb-release wget xdg-utils
```

[source](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix)

*Note:* even if installing all the dependencies can solve your issue, I highly recommend finding out the exact missing ones and install only them to avoid updating unnecessary dependencies!

Comment: I tried with "sudo ldd /usr/bin/chromium-browser/whereis | grep not" returns "ldd: /usr/bin/chromium-browser/whereis: No such file or directory"

Comment: you need to use it as (1) `whereis chrome` => it gives back e.g. `/usr/bin/chromium-browser/chrome` ; (2) `ldd /usr/bin/chromium-browser/chrome | grep not` => lists the missing dependencies. _Note:_ please apply your case to the example, the usage of `whereis` is linked in the answer, I link it once more: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-whereis-command-examples-to-locate-binary/

Comment: My "whereis chrome" returns "chrome:" and when I try "ldd chrome | grep not" it returns "ldd: ./chrome: No such file or directory"